# Test to see if data is close to zero

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, standard-deviation

I'd like to test if my data is close to zero. I can take the mean but I also want the standard deviation to be small. Is there a statistical test that produces a single number to quantify this?

For example, in the images below: The first image should indicate that data is far from zero, whereas the second one should indicate that the data is close to zero.

[image: Image 1]

[image]

Comment: I would say to determine your tolerance for not being zero and calculate the percentage of points that exceed that threshold. For instance, if you’re willing to have 5% of the points have an absolute value greater than 2 and 41 of 1000 points have an absolute value greater than 2, then you’re okay.

Comment: You might look at measures of accuracy, like *root mean square error*, *mean absolute error*, and so on.

Comment: You need to provide a quantitative way to measure "closeness" to zero.  It sounds like you just want to calculate such a measure: there's no testing involved at all.